# Unable to fetch all the names unraveling some dots on a map

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've written a script in python to parse the content of each box populated upon clicking on some dots available all over the map. I would only like to fetch the name of different properties.

[mapLink](https://map.search.ch/?was=immobilienmakler&wo=nahe+Bezirk+Lenzburg&b=low&pos=773248,184320&z=2)

There are around 6566 dots over there. I've caught a link from chrome dev tools containing 69 names.

My attempt so far:

```
import requests

URL = 'https://map.search.ch/api/poi_html.json?mode=hover&mx1=750592&mx2=789504&my1=193536&my2=232448&zd=256&d=area-f008d02987f8c91d&lang=en&base=485000,296000&tel_was=immobilienmakler&tel_wo=nahe+Bezirk+Lenzburg'

res = requests.get(URL).json()
for item in res['pois']:
    print(item['name'])
```

> ***How can I get all the names unraveling those dots?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's something to do with the query parameters. You'll have to either a) play around and see how each changes your output, or b) search through their documentation and find where that info is available. But you can easily play with those parameters by creating that dictionary and feeding that into your requests:

```
import requests

url = 'https://map.search.ch/api/poi_html.json'

payload = {
'mode': 'hover',
'mx1': '750592',
'mx2': '789504',
'my1': '193536',
'my2': '232448',
'zd': '256',
'd': 'area-f008d02987f8c91d',
'lang': 'en',
'base': '485000,296000',
'tel_was': 'immobilienmakler',
'tel_wo': 'nahe Bezirk Lenzburg'}


res = requests.get(URL, params=payload).json()
```

Gave me 70 elements in POIs

**My assumptions:**

What I'm assuming is this:

Usings Swiss Coordiante system
mx1 and mx2 - range of the window x-axis
my1 and my2 - range of the window y-axis

Changing these numbers can 'move' the map area, and then 'zoom in', or zoom-out'.

Ie:

```
url = 'https://map.search.ch/api/poi_html.json'

payload = {
'mode': 'hover',
'mx1': '649216',
'mx2': '858112',
'my1': '124928',
'my2': '568288',
'zd': '512',
'd': 'area-f008d02987f8c91d',
'lang': 'en',
'base': '485000,296000',
'tel_was': 'immobilienmakler',
'tel_wo': 'nahe Bezirk Lenzburg'}


res = requests.get(URL, params=payload).json()
```

Gives me 429 elements in POIs